# C# compiler null preconditions?

Tags: c#

I have a method like this:

```
T? GetItem<T>( string id, bool throwIfNull=false){...}
```

Is there an attribute I can use to tell the compiler that if I call `GetItem` with the parameter `throwIfNull`: true, the result will never be null?

Comment: That would be a [conditional post-condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#conditional-post-conditions-notnullwhen-maybenullwhen-and-notnullifnotnull) instead of a pre-condition, and it seems like that exact variant that you would need for this doesn't exist (`NotNullIfNotNull` is closest, but not quite right)

Comment: I'd suggest to actually split into `T GetItem<T>(string id)` for the throwing api and `bool TryGetItem<T>(string id, out T item);` for the exception-less api.

Comment: You're expecting different behaviors according to the signature. @Fildor's suggestion makes more sense in that case.